# Insignificant Predictor's p-value decreases as more significant variables are added, two of which are significantly correlated

Tags: statistical-significance, multiple-regression, regression-coefficients

As shown in pictures below, prisfmil50 (female incarceration rate per 1000 women) is insignificant in every combination tried from univariate to multivariate regression, but adding the following combinations of variables results in lower p-values that are close to 0.05:
povrate50 (p = .109),
povrate50 + pcthsonly150 (p =.078), and
povrate50 + pcthsonly150 + statepol (p = 0.089).

Univariate regression of the other variables has a p-value of 0.000.
Also, tests for multicollinearity and heteroskedasticity are unremarkable.

I am inclined to argue that this is a case of omitted variable bias where the correct missing variables would bring prisfmil50's p-value below 0.05 but I would appreciate it if someone could confirm my conclusion or correct it as I have to submit my research paper for grad school and my professor probably won't respond before its due (I may be overanalyzing this, but I'm trying to keep my 4.0 going into my second to last semester).

[image: Regression results]

[image]